# Encountering a error in inserting a video in android

Tags: android, eclipse

This my codes inserting a VideoView but when I run it , cannot be played.

```
VideoView v =(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
v.setVideoPath("/sdcard/ss.mp4");
v.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
v.start();
v.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html) for getting External Storage Path instead of static string as :

```
VideoView v =(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
v.setVideoPath(baseDir+"/ss.mp4");
v.setMediaController(new MediaController(Your_Current_Activity.this));
v.start();
v.requestFocus();
```

and make sure you have added External Storage permission in Androidmanifest.xml as:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: still, my video cannot be played..It says, "This video cannot be played". I just running it on my laptop not on my device, is't just okay?

Comment: @yam : sir, means you have video in any laptop device ? not in SDCARD on emulator

Comment: @yam : if this answer help u in solving current issue then accept it as answer by clicking on right sign in top of answer

Comment: the "ss.mp4" is on my laptop..my application was running only in my laptop where I am using now..I watched a tutorial that it can't be played in emulator just the mobile device, is't true?

Comment: @yam : add sdcard in emulator then place your video on sdcard . now your video play same on laptop as on device . just search for "How we add SDCARD on Android emulator" you will get lots of result

Comment: my android is on my "D" how is it?

Comment: @yam : man u are using my code in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295026/how-to-insert-video-in-android question but not accepting it as answer can i known why ?

Comment: i'm sorry I didn't know it because I am new here.But don't worry I checked it already.