# how to insert video in android

Tags: android, eclipse

```
VideoView v =(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
v.setVideoPath(baseDir+"/ss.mp4");
v.setMediaController(new MediaController(play.this));
v.start();
v.requestFocus();
```

I have a VideoView and here is my codes of inserting video but it didn't play,"This video cannot be played",  said the emulator.How can I fix this? Do you have another codes there inserting a video?

```
I need a code of inserting a video on android..
```

This is the Logcat:

```
01-12 20:35:07.451: D/dalvikvm(336): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 51K, 53% free 2560K/5379K, external 410K/517K, paused 114ms
01-12 20:35:12.480: D/dalvikvm(336): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 12K, 52% free 2587K/5379K, external 831K/1306K, paused 145ms
01-12 20:35:29.080: W/KeyCharacterMap(336): No keyboard for id 0
01-12 20:35:29.101: W/KeyCharacterMap(336): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
01-12 20:35:34.831: D/dalvikvm(336): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 26K, 53% free 2581K/5379K, external 911K/1552K, paused 488ms
01-12 20:35:38.681: D/dalvikvm(336): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 22K, 52% free 2601K/5379K, external 919K/1386K, paused 72ms
01-12 20:35:43.340: E/MediaPlayer(336): error (1, -2147483648)
01-12 20:35:43.840: D/dalvikvm(336): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 25K, 51% free 2677K/5379K, external 957K/1432K, paused 63ms
01-12 20:35:44.560: E/MediaPlayer(336): Error (1,-2147483648)
01-12 20:35:44.560: D/VideoView(336): Error: 1,-2147483648
01-12 20:37:37.191: D/dalvikvm(374): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 53K, 53% free 2560K/5379K, external 410K/517K, paused 81ms
01-12 20:45:07.301: D/dalvikvm(374): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 15K, 52% free 2596K/5379K, external 839K/1306K, paused 141ms
01-12 20:45:08.501: E/MediaPlayer(374): error (1, -2147483648)
01-12 20:45:09.040: E/MediaPlayer(374): Error (1,-2147483648)
01-12 20:45:09.050: D/VideoView(374): Error: 1,-2147483648
01-12 20:45:50.560: W/KeyCharacterMap(374): No keyboard for id 0
01-12 20:45:50.560: W/KeyCharacterMap(374): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
01-12 20:56:15.991: E/MediaPlayer(374): error (1, -2147483648)
01-12 20:56:16.351: E/MediaPlayer(374): Error (1,-2147483648)
01-12 20:56:16.351: D/VideoView(374): Error: 1,-2147483648
01-12 21:29:38.470: D/dalvikvm(410): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 54K, 53% free 2560K/5379K, external 410K/517K, paused 92ms
01-12 21:41:11.070: D/dalvikvm(410): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 14K, 52% free 2590K/5379K, external 831K/1306K, paused 111ms
01-12 21:44:57.890: W/KeyCharacterMap(410): No keyboard for id 0
01-12 21:44:57.900: W/KeyCharacterMap(410): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
01-12 21:45:01.270: D/dalvikvm(410): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 16K, 52% free 2623K/5379K, external 1211K/1714K, paused 85ms
01-12 21:45:02.370: E/MediaPlayer(410): error (1, -2147483648)
01-12 21:45:02.860: E/MediaPlayer(410): Error (1,-2147483648)
01-12 21:45:02.860: D/VideoView(410): Error: 1,-2147483648
01-12 21:45:06.531: W/KeyCharacterMap(410): No keyboard for id 0
01-12 21:45:06.531: W/KeyCharacterMap(410): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
01-12 21:45:08.041: D/dalvikvm(410): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 86K, 51% free 2674K/5379K, external 1054K/1432K, paused 74ms
01-12 22:28:36.910: W/KeyCharacterMap(410): No keyboard for id 0
01-12 22:28:36.910: W/KeyCharacterMap(410): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
01-12 22:28:39.100: D/dalvikvm(410): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 74K, 51% free 2642K/5379K, external 1211K/1723K, paused 86ms
01-12 22:28:40.040: E/MediaPlayer(410): error (1, -2147483648)
01-12 22:28:40.450: E/MediaPlayer(410): Error (1,-2147483648)
01-12 22:28:40.450: D/VideoView(410): Error: 1,-2147483648
01-12 23:15:26.885: D/dalvikvm(477): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 55K, 53% free 2560K/5379K, external 410K/517K, paused 105ms
01-12 23:56:35.670: D/dalvikvm(477): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 15K, 52% free 2596K/5379K, external 839K/1306K, paused 83ms
01-12 23:56:37.713: E/MediaPlayer(477): error (1, -2147483648)
01-12 23:56:38.410: E/MediaPlayer(477): Error (1,-2147483648)
01-12 23:56:38.410: D/VideoView(477): Error: 1,-2147483648
```

Comment: Which format is your video ? Can you give us logcat ?

Comment: 01-12 23:56:38.410: D/VideoView(477): Error: 1,-2147483648

Comment: my video is on mp4 format..That "ss.mp4" there on the codes above..

Comment: My logcat was too long if I copy it all to you..Not enough characters..Is the VideoView only will I give?

Comment: You can edit your question to add logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Error `-2147483648` means that your Video Format isn't correct.

Please check [Android Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).

Comment: how the format isn't correct?.mp4 is also a format of video right?

Comment: mp4 is just extensions, it doesn't sais the full video format or codec needed for that format.

Comment: @yam First try out different video so we can point that this is really the issue.